# Clojure in VSCode, Calva messes with compile path?

Tags: visual-studio-code, clojure, vscode-calva

So I setup a project with Lein, test and run, works fine. I open it in VSCode (where Calva is installed) and when running the same test: `lein run test` I get `C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\Temp\clojure-3239065182638120769.edn` So there is something when I open the project in VSCode with Calva that makes Lein suddenly look for the .clj files in my Local Temp folder. How can I make it stop looking elsewhere, why could it run it fine before I opened it in VSCode?

Comment: This kind of file is written in case of an exception.  So this is no source file, but contains the data around the error (e.g. the stack trace).

Comment: Are you trying to run tests for the project? You might want the command `lein test` rather than `lein run test`.

Answer (score 0):

`lein test` is the way to do it, here's a great write up on leiningen's test process: https://medium.com/helpshift-engineering/the-convoluted-magic-of-leiningen-test-selectors-2eb6c452dfcf

Another awesome thing is you can just run the tests in calva!
https://calva.io/test-runner/